# Comparing two columns of the same joined row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, join

I'm sure the answer is already in here somewhere, but I can't find what I need in particular.

It's very simple.  I have a one-to-many table via Wordpress (wp_posts and wp_postmeta). The postmeta table has an arbitrary number of  rows referencing the posts table.

I need to compare two values of different postmeta rows.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE
(
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'company'
    AND
    wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Company 01%'
) AND (
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'description'
    AND
    wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Potato%'
)
```

In the example above, I need to check the meta key "company" and "description" against the value within the same row. But at the same time, I need to check another meta key/value pair.

What is the correct way to compare these meta keys? I will need to compare about 10 seperate meta keys for each item (more in the future) so I would expect using too many subqueries would make it slow.

(FYI this is for use outside of WordPress, no need to inform me about the get_post_meta() function)

Comment: Related: [Custom WordPress SQL query for multiple meta values](http://kuttler.eu/code/custom-wordpress-sql-query-for-multiple-meta-values/) - Uses a separate join for each meta key. Seems incredibly inefficient if I am going to use 10+ keys. I need to maximize performance here, as this is for an ajax script.

Comment: It might look inefficient, but really it performs quite well

Comment: Oh does it? I wouldn't think so, maybe if I were comparing primary keys, but this is all strings. I guess I'll roll with that solution until I find a better one (if there is a better one). I'll definitely do some speed testing when we I get some more data to work with.

Comment: Yeah, but that part of the problem will exist regardless of query type becaue "%string" cannot use indexes

Answer (score 0):

Although I won't be convinced of the performance until I do some further investigation, the link I put in the comments of the original question ([here](http://kuttler.eu/code/custom-wordpress-sql-query-for-multiple-meta-values/)) seems to work. [Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry) has explained that this method "performs quite well" and so I'll go with that.

I guess I will post an answer to this question as I have it working now. If anyone has an improvement to this answer (if there is one) feel free to post it separately, I will definitely accept the best/most efficient query.

Finally, here is a simplified version of the query I am now using, with most the unecessary junk pulled out of it. The main objective here is to do a join for each meta field and assign it a name, so that field contains a unique row for the WHERE statement:

```
set @search_term_1 = '%This string is only found in post meta skills%';

select *

from wp_posts post

join wp_postmeta meta_comp ON ( meta_comp.post_id = post.ID AND meta_comp.meta_key = 'post_company' )
join wp_postmeta meta_reas ON ( meta_reas.post_id = post.ID AND meta_reas.meta_key = 'post_reason' )
join wp_postmeta meta_skill ON ( meta_skill.post_id = post.ID AND meta_skill.meta_key = 'post_skills' )
join wp_postmeta meta_method ON ( meta_method.post_id = post.ID AND meta_method.meta_key = 'post_method' )

where

  -- Check post title and description
  post.post_title LIKE @search_term_1
  or
  post.post_content LIKE @search_term_1
  or
  meta_comp.meta_value LIKE @search_term_1
  or
  meta_reas.meta_value like @search_term_1
  or
  meta_skill.meta_value like @search_term_1
  or
  meta_method.meta_value like @search_term_1


group by post.ID

limit 10
```